# metadata.finalizers[0]: Invalid value: "foregroundDeletion": name is neither a standard finalizer name nor is it fully qualified

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, azure-container-service

We have a full cluster running in production and suddenly it stopped working with the following error:

> ```
> The Deployment "authapi" is invalid: metadata.finalizers[0]: Invalid value: "foregroundDeletion": name is neither a standard
> ```
>
> finalizer name nor is it fully qualified

My current cluster version is:

> Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"7",
>   GitVersion:"v1.7.3",
>   GitCommit:"2c2fe6e8278a5db2d15a013987b53968c743f2a1",
>   GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-08-03T07:00:21Z",
>   GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"} Server
>   Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"6", GitVersion:"v1.6.6",
>   GitCommit:"7fa1c1756d8bc963f1a389f4a6937dc71f08ada2",
>   GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-06-16T18:21:54Z",
>   GoVersion:"go1.7.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

On the other hand, we cannot deploy either. The following message appear when kubectl is trying to deploy:

> ```
>    W1127 15:28:32.999978 42625 factory_object_mapping.go:423] Failed to download OpenAPI (the server could not find the requested
> ```
>
> resource), falling back to swagger
>           The Deployment "authapi" is invalid: metadata.finalizers[0]: Invalid value: "foregroundDeletion": name is neither a standard
>   finalizer name nor is it fully qualified
>           /home/builduser/myagent/_work/_temp/kubectlTask/1511796511792/kubectl
>   failed with return code: 1

YAML definition is shown below:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: authapi
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1  
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: authapi
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: authapi
        image: edgecontainerregistry.azurecr.io/portal.authapi:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m        
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5006   
        env:
          - name: ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: aspnetcore-config
                key: aspnetcore.env           
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: edgesecret        
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: authapi
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5006
      targetPort: 5006
  selector:
    app: authapi
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: autoscaling/v1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: authapi
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
    kind: Deployment
    name: authapi
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 10
  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 50
```

Any help on this?

Comment: Isn't there any code you could probably show us? And please edit your question it looks crappy.

Comment: @Hille I updated my post with YAML definition. As I said it was working during a few months without issues till now. Thanks a lot for your quick response on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug, fixed in 1.6.7+

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.6.md/#v167

> Fix Invalid value: "foregroundDeletion" error when attempting to delete a resource. (#46500, @tnozicka)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue running the following command:

```
kubectl delete deployments/authapi --namespace=production --force
```

Comment: Forcing a deletion is rarely recommended, unless you're sure you know what it implies. As a workaround, when a finalizer is blocking something, I would first try to edit the corresponding object and remove that finalizer from its metadata.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue on a cluster running version 1.6.0 while trying to upgrade a service running in the cluster. I could not upgrade the kubernetes cluster (to get the bug fix) right away.

Checked the pods in the deployment and noticed that one was stuck in "Terminating" state.

I described the pod to get the kubernetes node it was running on, got into the node, had this error on kubelet logs

> kuberuntime_manager.go:858] getPodContainerStatuses for pod
>   "_default(781d0645-23d3-11e8-bcca-00505690014f)" failed: rpc
>   error: code = 2 desc = unable to inspect docker image

Restarted Docker and kubelet on the node, the pod was now gone and could update the service without issues.